# How to prove $a^3 + b^3 +c^3 - 3abc =1 $, If a,b,c are infinite series as given in the description box below?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, complex-numbers

How do I prove that $$ a^3+b^3+c^3−3abc = 1 $$ if   $ a = 1+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}......$ , $b=x+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}....$ , $c=\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}......$ ?

I have tried the following :-

I discovered that $a+b+c=e^x$ and that $a=\frac{d(b)}{dx}$, $b=\frac{d(c)}{dx}$, $c=\frac{d(a)}{dx}$ . But I am unable to proceed further with these information.

Comment: Using https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475354/how-to-show-that-a3b3c3-3abc-abcab-omegac-omega2ab-omega2, $$a+bw+cw^2=\cdots=e^{wx}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: $$e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}$$ Set $y=\omega x,\omega^2 x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all three expressions  are considered as functions of $x \in \Bbb R$
(or $\Bbb C$, if you prefer):
$$
 a(x) = 1+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^6}{6!} + \ldots ,\\
 b(x)=x+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+ \ldots ,\\
c(x)=\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}+ \ldots
$$
then (as you noticed)
$$
 b'(x) = a(x) \,, \\  c'(x) = b(x) \,, \\ a'(x) = c(x) \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
f(x) = a(x)^3+b(x)^3+c(x)^3−3a(x)b(x)c(x)
$$
satisfies 
$$
f'(x) = 3a(x)^2c(x) + 3b(x)^2a(x)+ 3c(x)^2a(x)
 - 3 \bigl( b(x)c(x)^2 + c(x)a^2(x) + a(x)b^2(x)\bigr) = 0 \, ,
$$
i.e. $f$ is constant. Setting $x=0$ shows 
that $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$.

*Remark:* As Jack said, the expression can be written as a determinant:
$$
f(x) = \begin{vmatrix}a(x)&b(x)&c(x) \\ c(x)&a(x)&b(x) \\ b(x)&c(x)&a(x)\end{vmatrix} 
$$
and this representation can also be used to compute the derivative
(omitting the argument for brevity):
$$f' = \begin{vmatrix}a'&b'&c' \\ c&a&b \\ b&c&a\end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c \\ c'&a'&b' \\ b&c&a\end{vmatrix} + 
\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c \\ c&a&b \\ b'&c'&a'\end{vmatrix} \\
= \begin{vmatrix}c&a&b \\ c&a&b \\ b&c&a\end{vmatrix} +
\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c \\ b&c&a \\ b&c&a\end{vmatrix} + 
\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c \\ c&a&b \\ a&b&c\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc = \det\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c \\ c&a&b \\ b&c&a\end{pmatrix}=(a+b+c)(a+\omega b+\omega^2 c)(a+\omega^2 b +\omega c)$$
where $\omega=\exp\frac{2\pi i}{3}$ is a primitive third root of unity. On the other hand
$$ a+b+c = e^x,\quad a+\omega b+\omega^2 c = e^{\omega x},\quad a+\omega^2 b +\omega c = e^{\omega^2 x} $$
and $1+\omega+\omega^2 = 0$, hence $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc = e^{0x} = 1$.
This is just the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) associated to the differential equation $f'''(x)=f(x)$.

Similarly you may prove that there is a homogeneous polynomial $\sum_{cyc}p(a,b,c,d,e)$ with degree $5$ which vanishes over the fundamental solutions of $f^{(5)}(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: @rikodousennin: by the discrete Fourier transform $$\frac{1^n+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}}{3}$$ equals $1$ if $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a multiple of three and zero otherwise. This allows you to write $$\sum_{n\equiv 0\pmod{3}}\frac{x^n}{n!} $$ (and related) as an explicit linear combination of exponential functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy if you use
$$ a'=c,b'=a, c'=b.$$
Since
\begin{eqnarray}
&&(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc)'\\
&=&3a^2a'+3b^2b'+3c^2c'-3(a'bc+ab'c+abc')\\
&=&3a^2c+3b^2a+3c^2b-3(bc^2+a^2c+ab^2)\\
&=&0,
\end{eqnarray}
one has
$$ a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc\equiv C.$$
Using
$$ a(0)=1,b(0)=c(0)=0$$
it is easy to see $C=1$ and hence
$$ a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=1. $$

Comment: I wonder how this is different from what I posted ...

Comment: @MartinR, sorry, I didn't look at your answer carefully. I thought you used matrix to solve the problem.