# show that $a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}-3 a b c=1$

Tags: power-series

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text { If } \quad a &=1+\frac{x^{3}}{3 !}+\frac{x^{6}}{6 !}+\ldots \\
& b=x+\frac{x^{4}}{4 !}+\frac{x^{7}}{7 !}+\ldots \\
& c=\frac{x^{2}}{2 !}+\frac{x^{5}}{5 !}+\frac{x^{8}}{8 !}+\ldots
\end{aligned}
$$
then show that $a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}-3 a b c=1$

**My Aprroach:**

$$\begin{array}{l}
a=1+\frac{x^{3}}{3 !}+\frac{x^{2}}{6 !} \\
b=x+\frac{x^{4}}{4 !}+\frac{x^{7}}{7 !} \\
\begin{array}{ll}
c=\frac{x^{2}}{2 !}+\frac{x^{5}}{5 !}+\frac{x^{8}}{8 !} \\
\text { Now, } & a+b+c=e^{x} \\
 & \frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)\left\{(a-b)^{2}+(b-c)^{2}+(c-a)^{2}\right. \\
 & \frac{1}{2} e^{x}({........})
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

Further I am not getting no clue!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $a^3 + b^3 +c^3 - 3abc =1 $, If a,b,c are infinite series as given in the description box below?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2721608/how-to-prove-a3-b3-c3-3abc-1-if-a-b-c-are-infinite-series-as-given) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a%5E%7B3%7D%2Bb%5E%7B3%7D%2Bc%5E%7B3%7D-3%20a%20b%20c%3D1%24&p=1)

Comment: $$(a+b+c)(a+\omega b+\omega^2 c)(a+\omega^2 b+\omega c)=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$$
where $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/3)$.

Comment: yes! thanks a lot