# $a^3+25b^3+5c^3-15abc=0$ only if $a=b=c=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Q}$. I need hint to show that $$a^3+25b^3+5c^3-15abc=0$$ only if $$a=b=c=0.$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475354/how-to-show-that-a3b3c3-3abc-abcab-omegac-omega2ab-omega2

Comment: think with $ a^3+ b^3+ c^3 -3abc =0 $ condition. also

Comment: With $a=0,b=1,c=-1$ one gets $a^3+5b^3+5c^3-15abc=0.$

Comment: Multiplying by their
LCM$^3$,
we get the same thing with integers.

Comment: @user376343 Nice counterexample !

Comment: There was a mistake. I fixed it. I am sorry about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: First clear the denomiators and then use infinite decent! So, we can assume that $a,b,c$ are integer.

From $$a^3+25b^3+5c^3-15abc=0 \implies 5\mid a$$

So $a= 5a'$ and thus $$ 25a'^3+5b^3+c^3-15a'bc=0$$

so we get essentialy equation of the same form.  But we can 't proceede this inifinite times unless $a=b=c=0$.