# Find $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ (binomial theorem)

Tags: binomial-theorem

> $$a=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!}\\b=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{3n-2}}{(3n-2)!}\\c=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{3n-1}}{(3n-1)!}$$Find $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$:
>
> $(a)\ 1$
>
> $(b)\ 0$
>
> $(c)-1$
>
> $(d)-2$

Please help me solve this question.

I added $a,b$ and $c$. It gives me the expansion of $e^x$.

But i dont know how to use it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475354/how-to-show-that-a3b3c3-3abc-abcab-omegac-omega2ab-omega2

Comment: Can you factor the expression  $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$?

Comment: Try substituting $x=0$.

Comment: Yes but how can i find the terms a^2 b^2 and c^2?

Comment: FredH how i can solve it without substitution of anything?

Comment: Judging from the options, the answer is independent of $x$. So it should be the same for $x=0$

Comment: But how can i solve it without putting anything in place of x?

Comment: @TanR: discrete Fourier transform. $a(x),b(x)$ and $c(x)$ are linear combinations of $e^x,e^{\omega x},e^{\omega^2 x}$ with $\omega=\exp\frac{2\pi i}{3}$. But if you know in advance that $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ is constant, it is pretty useless to compute the closed forms for $a,b,c$: the evaluation at zero is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x=y\omega$ in the expansion of $e^x$ to get$$e^{y\omega}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y^{3n}}{(3n)!}+\omega\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{y^{3n-2}}{(3n-2)!}+\omega^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{y^{3n-1}}{(3n-1)!}=a+b\omega+c\omega^2$$since $\omega^{3k}=1,\omega^{3k+1}=\omega,\omega^{3k+2}=\omega^2~\forall k\in\Bbb Z$.

Similarly, put $x=y\omega^2$ in the expansion of $e^x$ to get$$e^{y\omega^2}=a+b\omega^2+c\omega$$Finally, recall that $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a+b\omega+c\omega^2)(a+b\omega^2+c\omega)=e^{y(1+\omega+\omega^2)}=1$ since $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$.