# Prove $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$ using factorization of symmetric polynomials

Tags: factoring, symmetric-polynomials

> Prove that $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$

This has been proved [How to show that $A^3+B^3+C^3 - 3ABC = (A+B+C)(A+B\omega+C\omega^2)(A+B\omega^2+C\omega)$ indirectly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475354/how-to-show-that-a3b3c3-3abc-abcab-omegac-omega2ab-omega2) and [Find $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ (binomial theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161841/find-a3b3c3-3abc-binomial-theorem) using algebra.

But is it possible to prove it using the factorization of homogeneous symmetric polynomials ?

**Attempt**

$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ is a homogeneous symmetric polynomial of degree 3 so the factors are to be either 3 one degree polynomials or two one-degree and one two degree polynomial, all symmetric. Elementary symmetric polynomials of 3 variables are $1, a+b+c, ab+bc+ca,abc$. Clearly $abc$ is not a factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(a,b,c)=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$.

\begin{align*}
f(-b-c,b,c)&=-(b+c)^3+b^3+c^3+3(b+c)bc\\
&=(b+c)(-b^2-2bc-c^2+b^2-bc+c^2+3bc)\\
&=0
\end{align*}

By Factor Theorem, $f(a,b,c)$ is divisible by $a+b+c$.

Therefore, $f(a,b,c)=(a+b+c)[M(a^2+b^2+c^2)+N(ab+bc+ca)]$ for some $M,N\in\mathbb{R}$.

$M=f(1,0,0)=1$

$2(2M+N)=f(1,1,0)=2$

So, $N=-1$.

Comment: I don't see what is implied by calculating $f(-b-c,b,c)=0$, could someone help me to understand this, thanks

Comment: It is the Factor Theorem. If $g(x)$ is a polynomial and $g(k)=0$, then $g(x)$ is divisible by $x-k$. Now if we fix $b$, $c$ and consider the polynomial $g(x)=f(x,b,c)$, then $f(-b-c,b,c)=0$ is just $g(-b-c)=0$ and therefore $g(x)$ is divisible by $x+b+c$.

Comment: I was doing just $f(a+b+c,a+b+c,a+b+c)=0$ but that is not how the Factor Theorem goes, $g(x)=f(x,b,c)$ clarifies everything thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{split}
a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc &=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3+c^3-3a^2b-3ab^2-3abc\\
&=(a+b)^3+c^3-3ab(a+b+c)\\
&=(a+b+c)((a+b)^2-(a+b)c+c^2-3ab)\\
&=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc).
\end{split}
$$