# $1$ as a common root of a quadratic equation

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

$$ax^2 + bx + c = 0\quad\text{and}\quad
bx^2 + cx + a = 0$$
have a common root.

In my book, it says that 1 is a common root for those equation?

Is this correct.

When we plug 1 in both the equations, we get $a+b+c = 0$, it says nothing about 1 being a root. Since we don't know if LHS is zero or not.

Where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Without further information, we cannot say that $1$ is a root. For example, if $a=b=c=1$, the two quadratic equations are $x^2+x+1=0$ and $x^2+x+1=0$. These clearly have a common root (as they are the same equation), but $1$ is not a root. From answers below though, we know that a common root $x_0$ must satisfy $$a\left(x_0^3-1\right)=0,$$ or equivalently (if $a\ne 0$) $$x_0^3=1.$$ Therefore, if you are given that there is a common **real** root, then you can conclude that $x_0=1$ is a common root.

Comment: It's possible of course that this question came up in a context where the reader is not expected to know about complex numbers (just real numbers). In that case, when they said there is a common root, it automatically meant real root and you can more or less ignore my comment above.

Comment: Could you clarify if the common root is required to be a **real** root?

Comment: You can also upvote my answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From first one you have $$c=-ax^2-bx$$ so put this in second eqaution and you get:$$ ax^3-a=0$$ Since $a\neq 0$ we have $x=1$ or solution of $x^2+x+1=0$.

Comment: rem if $a=0$ then $bx+c=0$ vs $bx^2+cx=0$, still has common root, not $1$ though.

Comment: @zwim but then it is not a quadratic

Answer (score 1):

Let $t$ is the common root,

$at^2+bt+c=0$

$bt^2+ct+a=0$

Solve for $t^2,t$

and use $t^2=(t)^2$ to eliminate $t$

and find $$0=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(?)$$

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475354/how-to-show-that-a3b3c3-3abc-abcab-omegac-omega2ab-omega2

Answer (score 0):

Let $t$ be the common root:
$$at^2+bt+c=0\\
bt^2+ct+a=0$$
Subtract and factorize:
$$a(t^2-1)+b(t-t^2)+c(1-t)=0 \iff \\
a(t-1)(t+1)-bt(t-1)-c(t-1)=0 \iff \\
(t-1)(at+a-bt-c)=0 \Rightarrow t=1$$