# Completely factoring $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, factoring

How do I completely factor $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc$ over the complex numbers? The first thing I did is factor this into $(a + b + c)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ac)$. But I am not sure how to factor $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ac$ over the complex numbers. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475354/how-to-show-that-a3b3c3-3abc-abcab-omegac-omega2ab-omega2?rq=1)?

Comment: Hint: As you might know from your inequalities training, $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - bc - ca - ab = \dfrac12\left(x^2 + y^2 + \left(x-y\right)^2\right)$ where $x = b-c$ and $y = c-a$. So now you need to factor a homogeneous polynomial in two variables $x$ and $y$. This is tantamount to factoring a (non-homogeneous) polynomial in one variable.

Comment: [Here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Olympiad-Treasures-Titu-Andreescu/dp/081768252X/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=mathematical+olympiad+treasures&qid=1604233692&sr=8-1) is another one, pages 3-4 in preview mode.

Answer (score 2):

$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a+b\omega+c\omega^2)(a+b\omega^2+c\omega)$, where $\omega$ is the root of $x^2+x+1=0$.