# if $x +2^{1/3}+2^{2/3}=0$ then find the value of $x^3+6$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if $x +2^{1/3}+2^{2/3}=0$ then find the value of $x^3+6$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Hint: $2^{1/3} = a$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475354/how-to-show-that-a3b3c3-3abc-abcab-omegac-omega2ab-omega2

Comment: I assume $x^{3}$+6=0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=-2^{1/3}-2^{2/3} \implies x^3=-2-4+3.2(x)=-6+6x \implies x^3+6=6x$$