# Can this be considered factoring $a^2 + b^2$?

Tags: factoring

We're told in middle school that there's no easy way to factor $a^2 + b^2$.

However, recently, and I believe this is common knowledge for more advanced mathematicians than me, I came with the following:

$$a^2 + b^2 = (a + b \mathit i)(a - b \mathit i)$$

So, I ask the better heads if this can be considered a factorization of $a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: Yes. It's a complex factorization, that's why it's not considered in middle school.

Comment: It's not admissible in $\mathbb{R}$, but it's surely a factorization in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It is a valid factorisation in $\mathbb{C}$, but in general, especially at an elementary level, "factorisation" refers to finding factors in $\mathbb{Z}$ or at least $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: This is a correct factorization using complex number coefficients. Another factorization using complex numbers is discussed in the MSE question [How to show that $A^3+B^3+C^3 - 3ABC = (A+B+C)(A+B\omega+C\omega^2)(A+B\omega^2+C\omega)$ indirectly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/475354/13130)

Comment: This is considered a factorization in the $\mathbb{C}$ set, it is just too ahead of your grade level. If your teacher did say "there is no easy way" then she means that it isn't possible to do it in $\mathbb{R}$ set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *can* be considered a factorisation of $a^2 + b^2$, but it rarely *would* be without some context indicating that you're supposed to be working in the complex numbers.

I now would like to convince you that $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ is a "better" factorisation than $a^2+b^2 = (a+bi)(a-bi)$.

For example, consider what happens when we work not in the integers (complex or not), but in the integers mod $n$; let's pick $n=5$ for concreteness.
Then $$2 \equiv -3 = 1 - 4 \equiv 16 - 9 = \underbrace{4^2 - 3^2 = (4+3)(4-3)}_{\text{the factorisation!}} = 7 * 1 = 7 \equiv 2$$ still holds; $a^2 - b^2$ factorises just the same as it ever did.
But what interpretation should we give to the symbol $i$ when we're working in the integers mod $5$?
Well, I guess maybe it's the square root of $-1$, i.e. the square root of $4$, i.e. $i = 2$ (how weird); and indeed $a^2 + b^2 = (a + 2b)(a-2b)$ continues to hold.

What about if we're working mod $3$, where there is *no* square root of $-1$? In that case, we have to do what we do in the reals and adjoin a new object $i$ which we declare squares to $-1$, and it's *not* the case that $i$ is equal to an integer mod $3$.

It's all got messy, because now if we want to interpret what $(a+bi)(a-bi)$ means, we now have to work out whether there is a square root of $-1$ mod $n$.

So $a^2 - b^2$ factorises neatly in *more general situations* than $a^2+b^2$ does.

Answer (score -1):

When we say “factoring”, we usually mean taking a positive integer and writing it as the product of two or more positive integers that are not equal to 1. We have a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b) which is a factoring when a and b are both integers. It is not a factoring if a = sqrt(1428) and b = sqrt(3000). The formula is correct, but a and b are not integers. Writing x as the product of two non-integers is trivial, let a ≠ 0 and b= x/a. That’s not a factoring.

What you found is a factoring in the Gauss numbers (complex numbers with real and complex part being integers) but we practically always want to factor in the integers.

Comment: Could you please use MathJax to format equations?